# Is it fine to run php website on root domain and wordpress blog on the sub domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications

My client's existing web app is built on php. He needs to get a blog on it. Is it ok to create a wordpress blog on subdomain? I doubt if it looks unprofessional. I can match color theme and designs but if it gives different user experience, could be unprofessional.  Please guide. Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the technical answer, yes, you can install Wordpress on a subdomain.

Here is [Slack](https://slack.com/), their [blog](https://slackhq.com) is a different experience, but the brand/design is cohesive enough that visitors know it is the same company. Therefore, I think you are fine to go ahead with this.